# Memory usage between Android 2.2 and 2.3

Tags: android, memory

I am developing an app that contains many images.  I have noticed that
the memory usage of my app is quite a bit higher in Android 2.3 than
in Android 2.2 - ultimately resulting in OutOfMemory errors while
loading bitmaps.  In researching this, I logged the result of
Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() in the onResume of the first
activity.  In Android 2.2, this outputs 5MB.  In Android 2.3, this
outputs 17MB.

I created a sample application to try to further narrow this down.
The sample app has 2 activities:  the first has a small image and a
button to launch the second activity;  the second activity has several
large images in a ScrollView.  You can download the sample here:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21709517/MemoryUsageExample.zip
When running this sample, Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() reports
3MB allocated after starting the first activity in both 2.2 and 2.3.
After launching the second activity, Android 2.2 still reports 3MB
allocated while Android 2.3 reports 17MB allocated.  Running "adb
shell dumpsys meminfo test.example" shows the same types of results.

Why is there such a dramatic difference between Android 2.2 and 2.3?
And more importantly, what should I be doing differently to prevent
using so much memory on Android 2.3?

**-----UPDATE-----**

After looking at the information Romain Guy posted, I decided to do a bit more playing with the various loading options.  The result shows that forcing the images to be loaded as RGB_565 does reduce the memory in Android 2.3, however it still uses more than 2.2.  In my example app, Android 2.3 now uses 10MB vs Android 2.2 using 3MB.  Further, I tried to force 32-bit by using ARGB_8888.  In this case, Android 2.3 uses 17MB, but Android 2.2 continues to only use 3MB.  The updated sample can be found here:  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21709517/MemoryUsageExample2.zip

What is the cause for these differences?  Is there more that needs to be done to get the memory usage closer to Android 2.2?  Also, is there a way to force images created via xml layouts into a particular format?  Can this be set application-wide?  Thanks.

**-----UPDATE 2-----**

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225562/how-to-change-the-size-of-bitmaps-when-loaded-from-xml), it is not possible to force images loaded via xml inflation to be a particular format.

I am still hoping for an answer on why Android 2.2 and Android 2.3 use different amounts of memory after forcing 16 or 32 bit.

Comment: Something is dodgy here, I am having the same problem. 2.3 is a disaster for my image manipulation app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871143/android-2-3-has-lower-vm-budget-than-2-1-and-2-2

Answer (score 6):

Android 2.3 loads images in 32 bits by default now. You can force 16 bits format using BitmapFactory.Options.

See http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/04/gingerbread-and-32-bits-windows/ and http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/

Comment: Thanks!  That explains it.  Would have been nice if this was mentioned in the Android 2.3 release notes.

Comment: Is there a way to choose the format for images loaded during the inflate of an XML layout?

Comment: I may have jumped the gun on accepting an answer.  See my update above.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that. Android OS preloads some images into native heap. The number of images preloaded depends on the OS VM budget for each process. Since 2.3 increased the VM budget to 32M, so it preloaded more images for each process than on 2.2 devices. Hence you saw more native heap usage in 2.3. This is only my guess.