# How to change the size of bitmaps when loaded from xml

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-image

I know I can change the size of bitmaps loaded programmatically by using BitmapFactory.Options (i.e. forcing 32 via ARGB_8888 or 16 bit via RGB_565). Is there an equivalent when loading bitmaps via xml (such as when defining drawables and background images in a layout)?  If there isn't a built-in switch available that configures this, is there a way to accomplish this other than stripping the graphics out of the xml and handling them manually?

Comment: I wonder if getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565); used before setContentView would make any difference to the memory usage on 2.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this from XML, you have to do it from code.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but an answer non-the-less.  Thanks.