# Android 2.3 has lower VM budget than 2.1 and 2.2?

Tags: android, memory-management

It seems like Android 2.3 has much smaller VM budget than 2.1 amd 2.2. I am suprised that the newer OS is more restrictive, I would expect that due to the development of technology one should have bigger memory allocation for an application (VM budget).

Because of this I cannot hold in memory big bitmap images, which is important for a graphics image manipulation application I am doing now. But it works fine in 2.1 and 2.2.

If I scale down my image with inScale to accommodate 2.3 then I lose on quality of my output.

Do you have any advice how to handle this difference between 2.3 and the previous versions based on your own experience?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Android 2.3's VM budget is actually higher (32 MB.) The difference is that Android 2.3 now loads all bitmaps in 32 bits (ARGB8888) by default instead of 16 bits.

See http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/04/gingerbread-and-32-bits-windows/ and http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/ for more information

Comment: As good as the answer may be, in my application I have set the view and all bitmaps to load or be created as argb_8888. It works on 2.2 fine on two devices but out of memory on 2.3.3 device. First I load 1900x2500 bitmap, this works on both, then I create three smaller bitmaps no larger than the screen, but 2.3.3 goes out of memory even at creating a quarter of the screen size bitmap after the big one is loaded. I wonder if there is something else that could cause this - how about static bitmaps, does 2.3 handles them differently?